# Add a textblock to grid dynamically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

My grid has 2 rows, 2 columns, and I want to add a textblock dynamically to first row, second column.

This is my code, which doesnt throw an exception but it doesnt show anything

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="768" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1366">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>


protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
            txt.Width = 200;
            txt.Height = 100;
            txt.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);

            var location = await InitializeLocationServices();
            txt.Text = location;

            Grid.SetRow(txt, 0);
            Grid.SetColumn(txt, 1);

        }
```

Comment: similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253744/adding-grid-and-controls-dynamically-in-wpf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are never adding your TextBlock to the grid. You should name your Grid (eg. x:Name="myGrid") and call myGrid.Children.Add(txt) at some point.

Comment: I only need that line to add it to the row and column I need?

Comment: No, you need it to add it to the visual tree. Otherwise - you are just creating a TextBlock and not adding it to anything. You still need to set all the properties as you do.